# How do I sum row before I sum column?

Tags: google-sheets

My table looks like this:

```
A | B
-----
1 | 10
2 | 20
```

If I use sum on B (`=SUM(B:B)`), I will get 30, but what I want is to first summarize each row (`A*B`). `1*10 + 2*20 = 50`. How would I do this in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A;B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to make third column like `С2=A2*B2` and then sum it.